# IOS layout issue

Tags: ios

If I'm right, in IOS, we don't have something as layout as in android. I'm new to IOS. Suppose I have two label, one on top of the other. Is it possible to make the label goes down. I went through the widgets in ios. I've not seen any linear layout

Comment: It's called [auto layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: this is only for xcode 5 and above

Comment: don't compare with other languages, travel through the apple documentation.

Comment: To change view position change frame of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you first to go through with getting started guide for iOS.

In this case you need to set size of UILabel dynamically which you can do using below code:

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296,9999);

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font 
                        constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                        lineBreakMode:yourLabel.lineBreakMode]; 

//adjust the label the the new height.
CGRect newFrame = yourLabel.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
yourLabel.frame = newFrame;
```

Comment: So, If I'm right, you can't just put the label there and expect it grow dynamically

Comment: no you have to code for it